# Why can't I pass a mut axum router to a function to configure routes?

Tags: rust, rust-tokio, rust-axum

I was playing around with axum while learning Rust, and wanted to try a change where I create the `Router` in one place but define the routes in another module. Since it failed spectacularly I thought about doing something easier first like configure the routes in the same module just a different function. No matter what I tried, passing mutable or reference Rust just doesn't allow it.

I just want to be allowed to configure the routes separately from the place I create the router. Here is my latest attempt:

```rust
use axum::{
    extract::Path,
    http::StatusCode,
    routing::{get, post},
    Json, Router,
};
use serde::{Deserialize, Serialize};
use serde_json::to_string;
use tokio;

async fn root_handler() -> &'static str {
    "Hello, world!"
}

pub fn configure_routes(app: &mut Router) {
    app.route("/", get(root_handler));
}

#[tokio::main]
async fn main() {
    let mut app = Router::new();
    configure_routes(&mut app);
    // run our app with hyper, listening globally on port 3000
    let listener = tokio::net::TcpListener::bind("0.0.0.0:3000").await.unwrap();
    axum::serve(listener, app).await.unwrap();
}
```

Why doesn't this work? And how can I configure the routes separately?

Answer (score 2):

You can use `router.merge(router: Router)` to combine several `Router` definitions. [Documentation](https://docs.rs/axum/latest/axum/routing/struct.Router.html#method.merge)

```
use axum::{
    extract::Path,
    http::StatusCode,
    routing::{get, post},
    Json, Router,
};
use serde::{Deserialize, Serialize};
use serde_json::to_string;
use tokio;
use axum::response::IntoResponse;

async fn root_handler() -> &'static str {
    "Hello, world!"
}

async fn health() -> impl IntoResponse {
    r#"{"Ok"}"#
}

pub fn app_router() -> Router {
    Router::new() //
        .route("/", get(root_handler))
}

fn health_router() -> Router {
    Router::new() //
        .route("/health", get(health))
}

#[tokio::main]
async fn main() {
    let mut routes =
        Router::new()
            .merge(app_router())
            .merge(health_router());

    // run our app with hyper, listening globally on port 3000
    let listener = tokio::net::TcpListener::bind("0.0.0.0:3000").await.unwrap();
    axum::serve(listener, routes).await.unwrap();
}
```

Answer (score 1):

[`Router::route()`](https://docs.rs/axum/latest/axum/struct.Router.html#method.route) consumes `self` and returns it, so you need to do the same:

```rust
use axum::{
    extract::Path,
    http::StatusCode,
    routing::{get, post},
    Json, Router,
};
use serde::{Deserialize, Serialize};
use serde_json::to_string;
use tokio;

async fn root_handler() -> &'static str {
    "Hello, world!"
}

pub fn configure_routes(app: Router) -> Router {
    app.route("/", get(root_handler))
}

#[tokio::main]
async fn main() {
    let mut app = Router::new();
    app = configure_routes(app);
    // run our app with hyper, listening globally on port 3000
    let listener = tokio::net::TcpListener::bind("0.0.0.0:3000").await.unwrap();
    axum::serve(listener, app).await.unwrap();
}
```

Comment: I'm sure they had their reasons, but that seems like an inconvenient API design?

Comment: this doesn't work i already tried it, i get the following error :
  
use of moved value: `app`
  --> src/main.rs:47:31
   |
32 |         let  mut app = Router::new();
   |              ------- move occurs because `app` has type `Router`, which does not implement the `Copy` trait
33 |         configure_routes(app);
   |                          --- value moved here
...
47 |         axum::serve(listener, app).await.unwrap();
   |                               ^^^ value used here after move

Comment: @Asher did you definitely put the `app =` before `configure_routes(app);` like Chayim did in additon to changing `configure_routes`' signature? The reassignment is missing in your error message.

Comment: @JaredSmith The method is mainly used within chaining. The alternative is to take `&mut self` and return `&mut self`, but then the final function also need to take `&mut Type`, and that is not always possible.